# I am using linq and I am getting the error "There is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first"

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
dc.Accounts.Where(a => blogs.Select(b => b.AccountID).Distinct()
           .Contains(a.AccountID));
foreach (Blog blog in blogs)
{
    blog.Account = accounts.Where(a => a.AccountID == blog.AccountID)
                           .FirstOrDefault();

    //this is done to access account outside ObjectContext
    blog.account = blog.Account;
}
```

In this code I am getting the value until the foreach loop blog, but then I am getting the error

> There is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it smell N+1 SQL problem; I would check that before any other fixes;

Comment: Is that `Distinct()` really necessary? The answers to `{1,1,2,3}.Contains(1)` and `{1,1,2,3}.Contains(4)` are identical to `{1,2,3}.Contains(1)` and `{1,2,3}.Contains(4)` respectively.

Answer (score 4):

This is usually caused when you have an outer and inner query, and the outer is still running. Usually you can fix this by forcing the outer query to complete; simply adding `ToList()` is usually enough:

```
var blogs = dc.Accounts.Where(a => blogs.Select(b => b.AccountID).Distinct()
       .Contains(a.AccountID)).ToList(); // <======= here
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable [Multiple Active Result Sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Modify your connection string to enable `MultipleActiveResultSets`

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=MSSQL1;" + 
    "Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI" +
    "MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```

Since you are accessing some navigational properties inside the loop you may be running into `Select N+1` problem. You can avoid this by eager loading.

eg:

```
dc.Accounts.Include("Blogs").Where(a => blogs.Select(b => b.AccountID).Distinct()
           .Contains(a.AccountID));
```